# Why is my SVG jumping on page load?

Tags: svg, responsive-design

The svg in the left column "jumps" on page load. When you first go to the [URL](http://sistersovercoming.org), it enlarges HUGE then scales down to the correct size for some strange reason. How can I fix this?

I've tried everything from percentage height to vh. Do I need to mess with the viewbox? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you haven't specified a width for anything and you are letting the browser resize and reflow the elements as the various objects load. Your SVG is inlined in the HTML and so is already present when the page loads.  But your `style.css` and `bootstrap.css` files won't be loaded until later, so until then, the SVG gets to occupy the whole page.

The SVG doesn't seem to be responsive.  It always seems to end up at a width of 662px. So just give it that width.

```
<svg width="662px" ...
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I figured it was something like that. It's so annoying! lol

Comment: Is there anyway to stop this from happening if you calling the svg from an image tage. I tried adding width and height attributes and using style width and height but neither affect it.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul LeBeau is correct in his evaluation and solution. But, if you also want to use pixel values when the page loads (to avoid the massive svg) and then use percentage values after the page loads, you can do the following with javascript and jQuery

Add concrete values for when the page loads:

```
<svg style="width:100px;height:100px;" class="svgClass"></svg>
```

Allow the css to kick in after:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //SVGs are huge upon first loading when using percents. So, set initial values to px and then remove
    $("svgClass").removeAttr("style");
});
```

I'm assuming something like the following is your desired class:

```
svgClass{
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
}
```